# Accept button is missing for Queued records in List View's on Lightning mode

Tags: lightning, list-view, queue

While submitting records to a Queue I am seeing user belong to the queue is not having an option to accept the records from the List view. When the user switches back to the classic from lightning the Accept button is available.
[image: Lightning View]

[image: Classic view]

I checked all options on the Lightning view, but couldn't figure out the way to get the Accept button in lightning.Is this the limitation in lightning or is there any way to achieve this on list views in Lightning mode?

Comment: Hi @rajasekhar, did you manage to create an Action for this? care to share the solution here?

Comment: Hi @iDog - No, I haven't implemented any action yet. I will update here if I implement this anytime soon.

Comment: Thanks rajasekhar.  I was able to add this, as a custom list view button, backed up with an appropriate Apex class. Let me know if you need any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create new Quick Action to show up on Lightning.

By default, in the Lightning mode Accept, Change Owner buttons are not visible which are usually getting displayed in Classic.

Refer this below trailhead. Migrate to Lightning Experience --> Lightning Alternatives to JavaScript Buttons -->

[Use Quick Actions, Custom Buttons, or Apex](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/modules/lex_javascript_button_migration/units/javascript_button_alternatives)